# The best way to prevent ransomware and virus?

Tags: antivirus, ransomware

I am using 
Avast free antivirus real time protection and weekly scan
Malwarebytes free anti malware weekly scan
Malwarebytes Anti-ransomware
EMET
good enough? Anything else I should do or choose another software?

Answer (score 5):

Malware is a fast evolving beast and their is no single solution which will protect you. But you can reduce the risk in various ways. First you need to know how the malware gets delivered:

- A major delivery vector for malware is mail, i.e. either as an attachment in the mail or mail which includes a link to some site you should visit. While many of the mails look suspicious others are get really hard to detect because they seem to provide expected or unexpected invoices or delivery notices from Amazon, Ebay, Paypal, DHL etc or even have the the of a friend as alleged sender. Typical attachments are various kinds of office documents, PDF or ZIP files containing JavaScript or Windows binaries. Sometimes the real type of the file is hidden, i.e. `document.pdf.exe` might look like a PDF from name and symbol but is actually a program.
- The other major delivery vector is the web. This will be illegal sites where you can watch movies, but more and more malware gets delivered through ads and through formerly trusted but now hacked sites.

Once the malware is on your system it needs to be run to start malicious part. This can be done with exploits or with social tricks:

- The major attack targets are Flash-, Silverlight and Java-Plugin, Acrobat Reader, Office and also the Windows system including Internet Explorer. Thus remove anything of these which you don't need (Java, Silverlight, Flash) and keep everything else always updated. There are lots of exploits out there which use problems in unpatched versions of Office, thus if you have some out-of-date Office software which is no longer supported you better remove it.
- Other attacks need your help, i.e. they lure you to enable macros in office, to update your Flash plugin with the alleged newest version which the attacker helpfully provides for you, to install some plugin or download program you need to access specific content etc. Or it tries to scare you with some dialog which claims to have found malware on your system and offers you a software to remove this malware. Don't fall on these tricks.

Thus how you can protect against these threats?

- Educate yourself and know what can go wrong. Then don't do anything which might be dangerous. Don't open unexpected attachments or links, don't install some software from the internet unless you are completely sure that it is definitely the one you need.
- Keep the system clean: Remove any software you don't need or which does not have any more updates. Always get the latest updates for the other software.
- Protect yourself with technologies like Adblocking and Antivirus. Use a browser which includes good protection technologies by itself - Chrome/Chromium is probably currently the best here. While none of these  provide fulls coverage they reduce the attack surface (even if some claim that Antivirus is dead).
- Always have current backups in case anything goes wrong. These backups should be offline so that they don't get affected. And you should have backups from multiple days in case you realize an infection too late and the backup itself is infected.

There can be much more hardening done, like only run whitelisted applications, disable Javascript in browsers, use virtual machines, using a more secure operating system ... . But after a while these protections get too much in the way of the normal work. Thus you have to find some balance between security and comfort and the risk you are willing to take.

Comment: This is an ok answer, but you should include that Silverlight is a prominent attack vector -- much more-so when compared to Java or Internet Explorer -- and significantly more-so when compared to MS Office or Adobe Reader. For example, much of the ransomware in the past six months (especially in the past 1-2 months) has been delivered via CVE-2016-0034 included in the patch rollup for MS16-006.

Comment: @atdre: I've updated the answer to include Silverlight.

Answer (score -1):

Anti-virus software is useless. In fact, it is worse than useless because it gives you a false sense of security. Even Symantec, a major provider of AV software, has publicly admitted what all security pros know: AV is useless ([Symantec exec declares AV is "dead", WSJ 2014](http://www.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702303417104579542140235850578)).

Typically a hacker will get control of your machine one of two ways: by sending you an email with a tainted attachment (like a Word file) or by you visiting a web site with a Javascript exploit. Note that the exploit can be in an ad on the site, not even on the site itself. In nearly all cases the hacker will have already made sure their Javascript hack or Word file passes all major AV tests, so your AV is useless to stop this.

To avoid getting hacked/infected, here are the steps you can take:

- Never open an email attachment you did not expect, even if it is from someone you know. Contact them and ask them first: did you send me that file?
- Keep your browser up to date. Most hacks are against older browser versions.
- Use any browser except Microsoft IE. Among major browsers, not only is Internet Explorer one of the buggiest browsers (and therefore susceptible to being hacked), but it is by far the commonly targetted. When I took a course in exploit development, IE was our classroom target. Use Firefox, Chrome, whatever, anything but IE.
- Use NoScript AddOn to block Javascript and Flashblock to block Flash. Do not run Javascript unless you have to. I always block all Javascript except on specific sites where it is needed and I whitelist only those sites. Flash is the same deal. Many hacks are distributed via Flash ads. If you are seeing pages in your web browser with dozens of blinking flash ads, you are asking to get hacked. Get an ad blocker and block Flash, unless it is KNOWN content that you want to watch like a YouTube video.

If you follow the steps above, you will avoid 99.99% of hacking attempts.

Comment: IE on current Windows systems has actually a more secure architecture than Firefox, i.e. proper sandbox etc. And while both Edge and Chrome were hacked at the latest Pwn2Own Firefox was not even considered for the hacking contest because it was considered too easy to hack. See http://www.tomshardware.com/news/pwn2own-2016-firefox-missing-in-action,31451.html.

Comment: JavaScript exploits are far less common than Java, Flash, or other plugin exploits.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I didn't say it wasn't. But Firefox is not targetted nearly so much as IE.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I added to the Javascript note, to include Flashblock and an ad blocker. Also, since most most Flash is Javascript enabled, using NoScript, indirectly will block most Flash ads.

Comment: @TylerDurden You completely misquoted the WSJ article. AV is ***NOT*** useless, Symantec never said so. It is still a necessary tool for protection, but cannot be the *only* tool.

Comment: @schroeder The exec said quote "AV is dead". What part of "dead" are you confused about? Dead means not alive anymore. Do you work at McAfee or something?

Comment: Dead != useless. I should not have to explain the basic logical fallacy you are making here.

Comment: Tyler - as an essential part of layered protection, AV blocks tens of thousands of malicious attacks weekly against most organisations. It isn't for zero day protection as other layers cover other gaps (well, AV with heuristics...) But without it your systems are screwed. That simple.